# changing cursor of CursorAdapter gives staleDataException

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

okay, so after going through tons of sites and blogs I have finally decided to ask this 'not so FAQ'.

I have 2 listViews. One as the 'category LV' and other as the 'item LV'. The functionality is quite simple- When the user clicks a category cell in the 'category LV', all the items matching that category should filter and appear in the 'item LV'. I do this by assigning the 'category integer' to every item in the database. So, when a category is tapped its integer id is taken and all the ids matching with it in the item database are loaded in the cursor.

PROBLEM:
I use the adapter.changeCursor(newCursor) method to change the underlying data in the adapter. According to the docs, this method replaces and closes the previously loaded cursor. I am getting this error

> 11-08 11:54:15.939: E/AndroidRuntime(2056): android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.

Down below is the code explained:

```
itemAdapter=new CategoryCursorAdapter(this, itemCursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER, "item_name",1,date,db);
    categoryLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s=((TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.category_name)).getText().toString();

            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("all")){

                itemAdapter.changeCursor(null);
                itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            else{
            itemAdapter.changeCursor(db.getItemCursor(s));
            itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }



        }

    });
```

I get the error in the CursorAdapter class:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(mcolumn==CATEGORY_LV){
    TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        tv.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(mColumnName)));
        tv.setTextSize(20); 
    }

    if(mcolumn==ITEM_LV){
        TextView item=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        TextView stock=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stock_status);

                   // I get the staleDataException at this place
        String s=mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(mColumnName));
        Button drag=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.drag_button);
        LinearLayout lv=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        drag.setFocusable(false);
        item.setText(s);
        item.setTextSize(20);
        stock.setText("Stock:"+mdb.getStockStatus(mdb.getItemCode(s), mDate));
        stock.setTextSize(15);
    }
}
```

One thing to note here is that I am using the same Adapter class to power both the listViews. However i dont think this can be a problem.

Comment: *One thing to note here is that I am using the same Adapter class to power both the listViews. However i dont think this can be a problem.* - this is most likely the problem. Don't share adapters. `changeCursor()` already calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` so don't call it again.

Comment: I am using the same adapter class but I am defining different objects of that class to use them in different listViews. Secondly, i have had no luck without using the notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: As you're handling the row view/data in the same method it wouldn't make sense to have an `else`(so you'll have `... else if (mcolumn==ITEM_LV) {...`) clause between the two `if` condition in the `bindView()` method?

Comment: how does it change the way the code is executed. Although to clear any doubt i have tried using else if but problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

In the last statement:

> *One thing to note here is that I am using the same Adapter class to power both the listViews. However i dont think this can be a problem.*

Just to confirm: Are you using the 1 Adapter instance or 2 instances of same Adapter class for both list views? You can not share the same instance for 2 list views, otherwise you will get exception like you got.

Comment: i am creating 2 different instances of the same class and using them at 2 different places